# What am I not understanding about getline+strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, getline

This is my first time using stackoverflow. I've been unable to find out the information I need regarding getline. I'm in a simple programming class for engineering transfers so the code that we write is pretty simple. All i'm trying to do here is put a user-defined number of questions and answers into two different arrays. My while loop looks like this (I was using a for loop but switched to while just to see if it would stop breaking):

```
int main ()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    string quest1[100], answ1[100];
    int size1, x = 0, num, count1, visit[100], shuffle[100];
    fstream flashcard1; 

    cout << "flashcard.cpp by NAME\n" << endl;
    cout << "This program allows user to manipulate questions and answers for studying.\n" << endl;
    cout << "\nHow many flash cards will be entered(MAX 100)? ";
    cin >> size1;
    cout << endl;

    while(x < size1)
    {
        cout << "Enter Question: ";
        getline(cin , quest1[x]);
        cout << endl;
        x = x++;

        /*
        cout << "Enter Answer: " << endl;
        getline(cin,answ1[x]);
        cout << endl;
        flashcard1.open("flashcard1.dat", ios::app);
        flashcard1 << quest1[x] << " " << answ1[x] << endl;
        flashcard1.close();
        cout << "Data Stored." << endl;
        */
    }
}
```

I noted out the answer entering part as well as the saving data to the file just for debugging. When I run the program it skips the getline for the first question, displays the second loop of "Enter question" and the getline works for the rest of them. So if I have a size1 of 5, the program only fills array positions 1-4. Please help.
This is a simple flash card program that will do the same thing as if you were to create flash cards to study and shuffle them.

Comment: `x = x++;` is Undefined Behaviour. It should just be `x++` (or `++x`, or `x += 1`, or `x = x + 1`, or `x -= -1`....)

Comment: That's because x++ and ++x both change x itself by in/decrementing its value by 1.  You can't guarantee that the assignment happens before or after this though, so x could be assigned the value of x++ before the increment happens or after it happens (the standard just doesn't specify this).

Comment: +1 for a good First Question on SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. +1! This is off-topic to your question, but 1) Please don't use `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. `std::cout << std::endl` is precisely equivalent to `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`. 2) Never say "using namespace std;", ever, even if (especially if) your book or professor tell you to. Importing the entire `std` namespace into your program creates hard-to-identify bugs.

Comment: @Rob I think that's a huge exaggeration about `using namespace std;`. As long as you know what the dangers are, you can do it in very controlled environments (like one-file short programs for example).

Comment: @all thanks for all the tips. I'm taking my first computer science class next semester. This simple C++ class for engineering was my first dive into programming and I really enjoy it. I'm going to pursue computer science as a major if I like the CS class next semester.  As far as my code goes regarding what Rob said. I don't even know what std::cout does. I don't think that this teacher is very good with C++, or he just wants to make the class as simple as possible. For lessons he just gives us ppt files which teach us 2-5 new C++ codes per class. Anyway thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason it's appearing to skip the first iteration is because when you do

```
cin >> size1;
```

You enter a number and hit the Enter key. `cin` reads the integer *and leaves the newline character unread on the buffer*, so that when you call `getline`, it's as if you immediately hit the enter key, and `getline` reads nothing (because it stops before reading the newline character), discards the newline, and puts the empty string in `quest1[0]`. And that's why the rest of the `getline`s work "correctly".

Add `cin.ignore('\n')` above your loop to get rid of the lingering `'\n'`, and that should make it work, barring other errors in your code.

And don't forget to change `x = x++` to just `x++` to avoid UB.

Comment: thank you! I haven't experienced such a helpful community in years!

Comment: @Brent if this answered your question, please make sure to click the checkmark beside it to mark this as the answer to your question.

Comment: I apologize. I was in class earlier and couldn't edit my program, but assumed this was the correct answer. When I added in cin.ignore('n) above my loop, the program just never brings up the first cout statement within the loop enless you just hit enter about half a dozen times

Comment: @Brent ok, then try `cin.ignore(1)`. I tried that myself and it worked.