# My while loop goes into it's second iteration before my switch statement executes completely, I'm coding in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void ReadFile()
{

    string fileName;
    ifstream inFile;

    cout << "Please enter the password for the external file: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    inFile.open(fileName);

}//End of ReadFile() function


int main()
{
    vector<string> studentName, studentNumber, studentClass;
    char option;

    while (option != 'g' && option != 'G')
    {

        cout << "\t\t\t" << "Student List Menu\n\n";
        cout << "A.  Reading the Student List from a file\n";
        cout << "B.  Adding Student's Informations into the Student List\n";
        cout << "C.  Displaying the content of the Student List\n";
        cout << "D.  Sorting and Displaying the content of the Student List\n";
        cout << "E.  Writing the Student List to a file\n";
        cout << "F.  Searching for a Student's Information from the Student List\n";
        cout << "G.  Ending the program\n\n";
        cout << "Please enter an option:     ";
        cin >> option;
        cout << endl;

        switch (option)
        {

            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                ReadFile();
                break;

            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                break;

            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                break;

            case 'E':
            case 'e':
                break;

            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                break;

            case 'G':
            case 'g':
                cout << "Thank you for using the program!";
                break;

            default: cout << "Invalid option choice\n\n";

        }

    }

    return 0;
}//End of main function
```

When I select option 'A', the switch statement calls the ReadFile() function, but when it asks for the "password" (the file name) to be entered, "Student List Menu" is read, which I think means the do-while loop continued to run while executing the ReadFile function, so it read the input until the newline character. What can I do to get it to run the option first, then continue through the do-while loop?

Comment: The problem is in the function getline(cin, fileName); Thats y its not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [What am I not understanding about getline+strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248239/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-getlinestrings)

Answer (score 2):

When you type

```
a
```

in your terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, two characters entered in the input stream: `a` and `'\n'`.

When you use

```
cin >> option;
```

on such an input stream, `'a'` is read first. The newline character is still in the input stream.

Then you call `ReadFile()`, which calls `getline(cin, fileName)`. That call gets an empty string since the newline character is still there in the input stream -- it doesn't wait for you to enter a filename. After that, there is nothing left in the input stream. Also, `ReadFile()` returns. That's why you see the student menu.

The fix to the problem is to ignore the rest of the line after `option` is read.

```
cin >> option;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Oh, that's right, I completely forgot about that pesky extra new line character, thank you! I would up-vote you if I could, but I just joined, thank you though!

Comment: `skipws` is on by default anyway... the solution here is to consume the rest of the line *after* the `option` before calling `getline`, for example - by using `ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

replace`getline(cin, fileName);`

with 
`cin>> fileName;`

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is due to the line

```
getline(cin, fileName);
```

You must use

```
std::cin.getline(fileName,name length);
```